# limit of a quotient of integrals involving $e^{-(x+y)^2}$ and $e^{-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am interested in computing the following limit:
$$
\lim_{r\ \to\ {+}0}\,\,\frac{\displaystyle\int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-r}^{r}{\rm e}^{-\left(x\ +\ y\right)^{\,\,2}}\,\,
{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y}{\displaystyle\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}
{\rm e}^{-x^{2}\ -\ y^{2}}\,\,\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y}
$$
My first idea was to use polar coordinates and then Fubini's theorem. However since we are not integrating over a "circular" region this didn't work out so well. Then, I remembered a corollary of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem which tells us that if $f \in L_{1}(\mathbb{R})$ then
$$
f(b)=\displaystyle\lim_{t \to{+}0}{}  \displaystyle \frac{1}{2t}\int_{b-t}^{b+t} f
$$
for every $b$ in which $f$ is continuous. We can try to apply this result to the denominator integral writing
$$
\int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-r}^{r} e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy= \left( \int_{-r}^{r} e^{-x^2} dx  \right)\left( \int_{-r}^{r} e^{-y^2} dy  \right)
$$
But it won't work for the other integral since we can't "separate" as in this case.

Any help?

In advance thank you very much.

Comment: If both of the integrands are positive, you can form an upper bound for the ratio by integrating the numerator over a circle circumscribed around the square and the denominator around a circle inscribed in the square. In fact, using the Gaussian integral, I believe then that the numerator will be bounded by $\pi$. Sorry, my comment applies if $r\to\infty$. In fact, you could probably apply this trick by rephrasing the two integrals in terms of $\frac{1}{r}$ and integrating.

Comment: The integral in the denominator can be written as
$$\left(\int_{-r}^re^{-x^2}dx\right)^2.$$
To use your corollary, square it, and get that the denominator divided by $4r^2$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Typesetting comment: Exponents are only single-character by default; to have a multiple-character exponent, you need to enclose it with braces. So, for example, `$e^ab$` yields $e^ab$, but `$e^{ab}$` yields $e^{ab}$. This is true even if the first character is a parenthesis or bracket.

Comment: Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem should be overkill here. Just calculate the top and bottom as multivariate Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some consideration I've found that this limit is trivial! You just have to use a similar corollary of the one you wrote:
$$f(0,0)=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{4r^2}\int_{[-r,r]\times [-r,r]}f(x,y)d(x,y),$$
when $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

So the limit is $1$.

Comment: Excuse me, what function are you applying your result to? The integral of the numerator converges to $0$.

Comment: To the one in the numeraror. I'm also using what I've commented above about the denominator.

Comment: can you add the reference or the proof of the result you mentioned? According to me, the lebesgue differentiation theorem isn't in general true for rectangles.

Comment: Wikipedia has some reference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem. This result is the same as the one you wrote but for the 2D case. The 1D case is saying that a function at a point can be approximated by integrating it in a sufficiently small segment around that point and dividing by the segment's length.

Comment: @SCarlsen LDT holds at least for families of bounded eccentricity, which clearly holds in this case (since we are integrating over squares). Merely multiply both the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{4r^2}$ and then take the limit of numerator and denominator seperately. (Note the numerator alone may go to zero, but won't when multiplying by $\frac{1}{4r^2}$)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen you're right! We can find the complete statement of the result in Folland's book. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comments.*

Using plain algebra and calculus, all antiderivatives and integrals involved are simple since we face a series of error functions.

By the end, we have
$$I=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-r}^{r} e^{-(x+y)^2} dx dy}{\int_{-r}^{r} \int_{-r}^{r} e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy}=\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi } r\, \text{erf}(2 r)+e^{-4 r^2}-1}{\pi \,   \text{erf}(r)^2}$$

Using series expansion
$$I=1+\frac{2 r^4}{9}\Bigg[1+\frac 1{15}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{a_n}{n!}\,r^{2n} \Bigg]$$ where the $a_n$ form the (unknown ?) sequence
$$\left\{8,\frac{254}{35},\frac{928}{105},\frac{1508656}{121275},\frac{59
   34464}{315315},\frac{140460752}{4729725},\frac{2326232576}{48243195},\cdots
   \right\}$$

Using the above terms only, this gives a very good approximation up to $r=1$

Comment: Interesting approximation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

In fact the problem can be solved simply applying **L'Hopital's rule**. Let $$F(r)=\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-(x+y)^2}dxdy=\int_{-r}^{r}(\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-(x+y)^2}dy)dx$$
$$G(r)=\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy=(\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-x^2}dx)^2$$(These two transformations apply the Fubini theorem.)

We recall that if $$\Phi(r)=\int_{f(r)}^{h(r)}\psi(r,x)dx$$,then $$\Phi'(r)=\psi(r,g(r))g'(r)-\psi(r,f(r))f'(r)+\int_{f(r)}^{g(r)}\psi_r(r,x)dx$$

And this formula fits the condition for determining $F'(r)$, where $$\psi(x,r)=\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-(x+y)^2}dy$$

After boring but straightforward calculation we have
$$F'(r)=2\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-(r+y)^2}dy+2\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-(r-y)^2}dy\longrightarrow 0$$  $$(r\longrightarrow 0)$$
$$F''(r)=4+4e^{-4r^2}\longrightarrow 8$$   $$(r\longrightarrow0)$$

$$G'(r)=4e^{-r^2}\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-x^2}dx\longrightarrow 0$$ $$(r\longrightarrow 0)$$
$$G''(r)=4(2e^{-2r^2}+e^{-r^2}2r\int_{-r}^{r}e^{-x^2}dx)\longrightarrow 8$$ $$(r\longrightarrow 0)$$

Then the L'Hopital's rule claims that the answer is $\frac{8}{8}=1$